Automatically redefining Quotation Marks in LaTeX
Is there a way to automatically make the input of "quote", give the output that  ``quote" would? Meaning that "quote" outputs “quote”. The language is norwegian.
I tried \usepackage[norsk,shorthands=off]{babel}, after having a different issue with how quotes appeared, but this made all input of " appear as a right quotation mark (”), so that "quote" outputs ”quote”.

Welcome to TeX.SE! have you tried to use package csquotes?

Especially the code in the question itself, the answer is not so relevant in this case.

I'm afraid I can't get that to work either, but maybe I'm using it wrong. All " still appears as it did, and the \enquote function only produces guillemets, no matter what argument I put in \MakeOuterQuote and \MakeInnerQuote. @Marijn

If the duplicate question does not help, please show a minimal working example of what you've tried.

`
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[norsk, shorthands=off]{babel}
\begin{document}
"quote"
\end{document}
This gives me an output of”quote”` (both right quotation marks).
No using \MakeOuterQuote or \MakeInnerQuote changed that. As far as I understood all that does is change the input that gives a quotation in the document, but I want to change what the output is. @cabohah

One way is type  "quote" in texworks, because it will be  rewrited  automatically to ``quote''. Another is write the text elsewhere, and save the but text as foo.md,  and then pandoc -f markdown  -s -t latex foo.md -o foo.tex but of course, this could also escape active characters as % or & , whereas some non active characters could  be interpreted as markdown syntax, so it is debatable if this could help or hinder you

For the code given in your comment above (which should have been an edit to the question) using \usepackage[autostyle=false]{csquotes} \MakeOuterQuote{"} gives the desired behavior.

That worked perfectly, thank you! @Marijn
